# RSpec sees xits but no other tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rake

So, whenever I run "rake spec" in my application directory, I see this:

```
admin@nurvus:~/workspace/spec $ rake spec
(in /Users/admin/workspace/)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Rake tasks in vendor/plugins/abingo/tasks, vendor/plugins/delayed_job/tasks, vendor/plugins/funkytown/tasks, vendor/plugins/funkytown/tasks, vendor/plugins/git_helper/tasks, vendor/plugins/git_helper/tasks, and vendor/plugins/jrails/tasks are deprecated. Use lib/tasks instead. (called from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p299/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/tasks/rails.rb:10)
** Invoke spec (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:load
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:schema:load
** Execute spec
No server is running
Running specs locally:
DEPRECATION WARNING: require "activesupport" is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 3. Use require "active_support" instead. (called from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p299/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/activesupport.rb:2)
DEPRECATION WARNING: require "activerecord" is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 3. Use require "active_record" instead. (called from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p299/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/activerecord.rb:2)

Example disabled: should return the next ordered survey
Example disabled: should not redirect unsupported browser

admin@nurvus:~/workspace/spec $
```

There are over 2500 tests that just aren't getting run, but it's obviously parsing the files, since the disabled examples are being seen.  Any top-level thoughts on this?